# How do I slant variables when using eulervm?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontspec, italic, eulervm

Using fontspec and xetex, when in text mode I can define:

```
\renewcommand{\textsl}[1]{{\fontspec[FakeSlant=0.2]{Neo Euler} #1}}
```

and I get slanted characters using Neo Euler (to fake the missing italics).

I want to do the same thing with eulervm in math mode, and redefine plain math variables to be slanted. Before even specifying that I want variables to use that format, I can't even get to use fontspec in math mode, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\mathsl}[1]{{\fontspec[FakeSlant=0.5]{Neo Euler} #1}}
```

Does not produce a slanted font when I have $\mathsl{x}$. Any suggestions on how to get slanted text in math mode?

Once that's done, how would I go about requesting that all scalar variables be typeset in that format in math mode? (presumably using \DeclareMathAlphabet, but not sure how)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Euler has been designed upright and has no slanted variants.

Comment: Thanks! I realize that there are is no slanted/italic version, but I can fake it in text mode, so presumably I can also fake it in math mode as well, right?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understand correctly. If your math font is Neo Euler, just use `unicode-math` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit,FakeSlant=0.5]{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}
$xyz\ne\mathit{xyz}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the result is really poor: the Euler fonts have specifically been designed as upright and slanting them destroys their beauty.

Comment: Yes, I agree it doesn't look great but representing scalars as slanted helps parse some linear algebra equations faster. It still isn't clear to me though how I make this be the default math mode character style, without having summations and other symbols also be slanted.

Comment: @user36930 Just remove the `math-style=upright` option. But I wouldn't use Euler in this case.

Comment: And a small followup, is there a way to exclude \sum from using Neo Euler? (and use the AMS default instead)

Comment: @user36930 `\setmathfont[range=\sum]{Latin Modern Math}`; you can do multiple `range` assignment. Consult the documentation of `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 0):

Linux fonts Libertine and Biolinum might work as alternates depending on your purpose (although puritans may disagree).

Using package `eulervm` with option `small` helps bringing x-height and stroke width closer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[small]{eulervm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathlib}{OT1}{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbio}{OT1}{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
xyz &\ne \mathlib{xyz}\\
\mathbio{Euler} &\ne Euler
\end{align}

\end{document}
```